# ASP.NET Identity customizar com própria base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação, asp.net-identity

Eu já tenho minha base pronta com a tabela login, e nao queria alterá-la, ai gostaria de saber se tem como customizá-la com as tabelas que já tenho! e como fazer isso!

Abaixo o mapeamento da tabela de login em minha base:

```
public partial class cnet_logon
{
    public long id_pessoa { get; set; }
    public long id_pessoaContato { get; set; }
    public string userpassword { get; set; }
    public bool ativoAcesso { get; set; }
    public bool ativoConsumo { get; set; }
    public virtual ncl_pessoa ncl_pessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual ncl_pessoaContato ncl_pessoaContato { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar como está seu código no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Então na verdade eu só tenho o mapeamento pronto, da base de dados com as classes, não sei como consumir e adaptar com o asp.net identity para fazer a authenticação

Comment: Favoritei. Dando uma folga nos meus projetos faço uma resposta bem completa pra você.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, ficarei no aguardo

Answer (score 1):

Como ela usa o Entity Framework para acessar usuários, basta mapear sua classe de usuários e fornecer o contexto para a `UserStore`.

Comment: Mas como eu poderia fazer isso, é minha primeira vez trabalhando com asp.net identity, teria como mandar um exemplo?

Comment: É uma questão mais ligada ao Entity Framework do que ao ASP.NET Identity em si. Como o código acessa o banco de dados? Usa Entity Framework, outro ORM ou ADO.NET puro? 
Se usar Entity Framework, basta criar o contexto do usuário e passá-lo na criação da `UserStore`. Caso contrário, você precisará de implementações customizadas de `IUserStore`.

Comment: é via ENTITY FRAMEWORK

Comment: a parte q não entendo é como faria a junção da tabela que tenho com a UserStore.Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: O Entity Framework não tem a classe de context da sua tabela de usuários? Você deve usar justamente ela para instanciar um objeto UserStore, que ele faz as operações necessárias pra você.